# PDE with Integral constraint

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations, differential-equations

I am trying to solve the Non-linear Schrodinger equation

$-\Delta \psi(r) + \psi(r) - |\psi(r)|^2\psi(r) = 0$ where $r \in \Omega$

In a square domain ($(x,y) \in \Omega$ where $\Omega=[0,1]\times [0,1]$) with the Dirichlet condition

$\psi(r) = 0$ for $r \in \partial \Omega$

and with the additional constraint

$\int_\Omega d^2r \, |\psi(r)|^2 = 1$

Does somebody know how to include the integral condition into NDSolve?

Thanks in advance

Alvaro

Comment: Hola Alvaro, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. Here its considered helpful to share your code attempts, in a well [formatted](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) easy to copy&paste form. Don't erase your nicely formatted $\LaTeX$, just add Mathematica code in addition.

Comment: Whoever wrote this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_Schrödinger_equation used mathematica...

Comment: You might also want to look at http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CausalInterpretationOfTheNonlinearSchroedingerEquationAnAnal/ though this does not look very promising http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502814/inverse-scattering-method

Comment: A Lagrange multiplier doesn't work?

Comment: Hello, actually my first attempt was using a Lagrange multiplier, but NDSolve accepts only algebraic constraints, as for example: $f(r)+g(r)=1$. To put it differently it seems to me that it only accepts local constraints and not non-local as $\int_\Omega d^2 r \, |\psi(r)|^2 = 1$. In fact my question is precisely how to circumvent this problem. Thanks

Comment: I may add that fixing the solution's norm is essential because if the $f$ is a solution of the NLS equation $\alpha \cdot f$ with $|\alpha| \neq 1$ is not a solution, i.e. the normalization matters.

Comment: Isn't there a uniqueness result for the Dirichlet problem for nonlinear elliptic equations of this kind? If so then $\psi \equiv 0$ is the only solution to the problem you posed.

Comment: I do not know about the uniqueness properties of the NLS equation, but in relation with the solution, it is possible to formulate the NLS equation as minimization problem which will give a Ginzburg-Landau functional. In this case you can add the constraint of $\int_\Omega d^2r \, |\psi(r)|^2 = 1$ which force you to obtain a solution different from $\psi=0$

Comment: The problem with the minimization approach is that it is very difficult to formulate without going to a matrix formulation, which I would like to avoid. In particular because this approach is very difficult to modify when adding terms.